# How to calculate how much current can lithium battery provide?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo

I need to know how much current can produce battery below? And how to increse current and voltage with 2 batteries like this below?

Here are some details:

```
Nominal Capacity : 250mAh
Size : Thick 4MM ( 0.2MM) Width 20MM ( 0.5MM) * Length 36MM ( 0.5MM)
Rated voltage : 3.7V
Charging voltage : 4.2V
Charging temperature : 0 C ~ 45 C
Discharge Temperature : -20 C ~ + 60 C
Storage temperature : -20 C ~ + 35 C
Charging current: standard charge : 0.5C, fast charge : 1.0C
Standard charging method : 0.5C CC ( constant current ) charge to 4.25V, then CV ( constant voltage 4.2V) charge till charge current 0.05C
Maximum charge current : 1C
Maximum discharge current : 1C
```

Comment: Where is the product link to the battery?

Comment: Here:http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/3-7V-lithium-polymer-battery-042035-402035-230mah-MP3-MP4-MP5-Bluetooth/818416_32422805705.html

Comment: The link says 230 mAh not 250 mAh but as for the rest of it, I'm not understanding the language. A data sheet link is better i.e. a pdf document.

Answer (score 4):

> Nominal Capacity : 250mAh
>
> Maximum discharge current : 1C

That means that it is rated to provide 250mA of current.

As always, voltage can be raised by putting cells in series (but watch out for balancing issues), and current can be raised by putting cells in parallel. If both must be raised then a full array of cells must be used.

Comment: How can create full array of cells? Did you get calculation: 250 x 1?

Comment: With 2 cells you can increase voltage or current but not both. For example if you want 2*voltage and 3*current you need 2*3 = 6 cells.

Comment: @VladimirDjukic: The proper unit on charge/discharge rate is h**-1. It is called "C" by convention.

Comment: Is that mean if I increase voltage and current with new cells I will need to change current and voltage when charging batteries?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic: I'm not sure I understand the question. As long as there is balancing circuitry, cells can be charged in series. And cells charged in parallel will take longer to charge, but can still be charged as normal nonetheless.